# Orientação de tela no android

Tags: android

Tenho uma activity que tem está declarado no manifesto como portrait, e tenho uma galeria de imagens, onde quando clicado em alguma das imagens eu lanço esse código:

> getSupportActionBar().hide();
>   getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

para fazer com que a imagem fosse redirecionada ao colocar o aparelho na horizontal eu tentei isso:

> activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);

funciona mais ignora os comandos de esconder a actionBar e a flag fullscreen setada anteriormente.

Answer (score 2):

Tenta colocar assim:

> ```
> activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
> ```
>
> getSupportActionBar().hide();
>   getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);